# How can I improve the performance of this MySQL INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query

```
SELECT p. *
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN followings AS f ON p.id_user = f.id_user
WHERE 
f.id_me =(my id)
ORDER BY id LIMIT 11
```

I have indexes for:

- `id_user` in the `posts` table
- `id_user, id_me` in the `followings` table.

100K rows in the `followings` table, 30K rows in the `posts` table.

My question is it takes more than 1 second, is it possible to write this query that takes a few milliseconds?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` and post it.

Comment: rule of thumb: any field used in a `join` or a `where` and sometimes even an `order by` should have an index on it. but other than that, there's very little in your query that could be optimized at the query level - either add indexes as needed, or get a faster DB server.

Comment: which table is the order by "ID" associated.  You should get in the habit of queries with table.column... or alias.column as others trying to help know correct context of table origins.

Comment: Try swapping the columns in the index on `following`.  Go `id_me, id_user`.  Basically for indexes to be most useful they need to index the most "selective" thing in the where clause first.  Think about how you would look for the data and index it that way...

Comment: Whilst it is important to understand which columns need to be indexed (see the comment by @MarcB), it is also *vital* that you understand the order in which they need to be used.  B-tree indexes work in a very particular way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p. *
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_me, id_user from followings order by id_me, id_user) AS f ON p.id_user = f.id_user
WHERE 
f.id_me =(my id)
ORDER BY id LIMIT 11
```

By creating a sub_query you are putting an index on the ID's without altering the table. This should speed up time. If this does not work and it is using an improper index for this query, you can use force_index...but this should help a bit...

Comment: how would this be any faster? Now you're running two queries instead of one.

Comment: because it's limiting the columns he's pulling from the second table, also the table that he is not pulling any info from in the select...

Comment: if it doesn't help then fine, but it's all he can really try...short of adding indexes that weren't appropriately in place to begin with..

Comment: i added an index for timestamp column in the posts table now it takes 10 times faster but im not using timestamp column in my query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select p. *
    from posts p
    where p.id_user in 
    (select f.id_user
      from 
     followings f 
     where 
     f.id_me =(my id) )
    order by id limit 11
```

Now you are not doing the cross product between the 2 tables and then filter it....now you filter the big table(followings) first, so it haves to be faster than a join.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your query, and your indexes aren't far off.

In order to get the most out of indexes it's important to understand not just *which* columns are going to be used, but the most efficient order in which they *should* be used in order to get your data out.

Replace your index on `following` with one that is `id_me, id_user` (the reverse of what you described).

That way MySql can:

- Find the right rows in `following` first by looking up in a small slice of your index (being the best way to reduce the amount of work it needs to do)
- Use the `id_user` data in the index on `following` in order to...
- Find the right rows in `posts` using your existing index on that table.

Basically try to work out how *you* would find the data and then provide indexes to help MySql do it for you.

Comment: Didn't I do this in sub-query?

Comment: Yes - you are asking MySql to do this, I'm helping you create the indexes that mean MySql can do it in a timely fashion (as per your question).  I.E. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your query.

Comment: Apologies - I thought the questioner posted the comment.  No @Hituptony you didn't.  You rephrased the query, but that doesn't change the fact that the indexes aren't there to support the way MySql needs to get to the data.  Ergo it's likely the MySql will do the same in your example as it would in the original query.  The phrasing of queries is not the same as the definition of execution path.

Answer (score -2):

If adding indexes is an option, add one for `id` (whichever table that is from), since it is used for the `ORDER`. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/
I had a query on large tables drop from 30 seconds to 3 seconds by adding an index to the `ORDER` clause.

Also recommended is to have the `ORDER` column come from the leading table. So if `id` is from the `posts` table, then it is already correct, but if not, reverse the tables in the query, selecting `FROM followings` and `JOIN posts`.

Finally, if `id_user, id_me` is a multi-column index, it could be useful to change it to two separate indexes, as it isn't taking advantage of the index in the `WHERE` clause. As a multi-column index, assuming the `id` you are looking for is rare, it will still have to scan a large portion of the table to find the `limit` you requested. 
As mentioned by others, reversing the order of the multi-column index to `id_me,id_user` would help because the `WHERE` clause narrows the results down the fastest (also assuming the `id` you are looking for is rare), but I don't know whether it would still take advantage of the `id_user` part for the join, though this would have a smaller effect.

Comment: This won't help as it won't help MySql get to the data quickly.  The amount of data that needs to be sorted will be negligible in comparison to the amount of data that needs to be sifted through to find the right data to sort.